# How to wait for a variable is loaded before using it in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, load, expression, directive, ui-sref

I am trying to develop a directive for a dynamic, custom toolbar with a caption block and CRUD operation links based on the view the user is on. For the CRUD operation links, I am trying to pass the ui-router state information. The directive works fine as long as I pass static strings for the CRUD links to directive; however, it fails when I try to pass ui-state with parameters as shown in the code below. It appears that the directive template gets loaded before the ui-state parameter is evaluated. Appreciate if someone could recommend a fix.

**Directive: navbarForm.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("navbarForm", function() {
    return {
       replace: true,
       restrict: "E",
       templateUrl: '/assets/templates/directives/navbarForm.html',
       scope: {
         title: '@',
         addLink: '@',
         editLink: '@'
       }
    }
});
```

**Template: navbarForm.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="title">
      <p>{{title}}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-if="addLink" class="action">
          <a ui-sref="{{addLink}}" class="ion-ios-plus-empty"></a>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="editLink" class="action">
          <a ui-sref="{{editLink}}" class="ion-ios-compose-outline"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**View: taskDetail.html --- This works**

```
<navbar-form
  title = "My Title"
  add-link = "taskAdd()">
</navbar-form>

<!-- markup to show task detail -->
```

**View: taskDetail.html --- This fails**

```
<navbar-form
  title = "My Title"
  edit-link = "taskEdit({id:task.taskId})">
</navbar-form>

<!-- markup to show task detail -->
```

Comment: I answered a similar question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30926767/968155

Comment: Thanks, adding ng-if in the view and adding {{}} around task.taskId resolved the issued.

Comment: That is, changed "taskEdit({id:task.taskId})" to "taskEdit({id:{{task.taskId}}})" to resolve the issue. Also had to add ng-if to the form section below the the toolbar to fix the html rendering sequence; otherwise, the toolbar rendered after the rest of the page was rendered.

Comment: Is there a way to call DeleteTask function that is in TaskDetailController from the navbarForm.html using ng-click?